# How to allow a user and his collaborators to work on the same routes with the same data

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I am new to Laravel and would like a suggestion from you.

I had in mind to create a management project and make sure that both the user (which is entered by me in the db) and his collaborators can work on the same project (therefore on the same data and on the same routes), obviously each with their credentials.

Is it possible to do this? If so, could someone suggest me how to do it?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

if you are thinking about not letting other people to work on projects they don't have authority over, try **Gates** in laravel , you can find more about them in laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization).

if you need somthing like admin , user access too , I suggest looking at this [package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

good luck!

Comment: i saw that it is based on id. But if the user who has id = 6 has his own project and his two collaborators have id = 9 and id = 15 how do you establish with the gates that his collaborators can also work on it?

Comment: @Sarah how do you determine those 2 people are the collaborators on that project?

Comment: @Sarah , you should create some relation between project & collaborators, you can use that to determine if the collaborator has valid access when u want to change a project, you can get the project id & the collaborator id, then u can check if there is a relationship or not. with just bare ids you can do anything. read about relations

Comment: @3VIL ok this far I had arrived. How do I connect the main collaborator of the group with the other collaborators who work together with him on the same project?

Comment: @Sarah as I said, you can use relations of the project table with users. read about them in laravel docs there are examples for better understanding, if you expect someone to write your code you can't find it here